# How to split String after CONCAT over the repetition of Row Number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables as shown:

I want to CONCAT the two tables by joining them and split them over the repetition of Row Number.

```
    CREATE TABLE #portiontable (
 PortionKey NVARCHAR(100),
 RN         INT,
 )

CREATE TABLE #finaltable (
 Value     NVARCHAR(100),
 RN         INT,
 )

 INSERT INTO #finaltable (Value,RN)
 VALUES ('KRM__21X0E',1),
        ('C',2),
        ('',3),
        ('',4),
        ('KRM__21X0E',1),
        ('C',2),
        ('',3),
        ('',4)
INSERT INTO #portiontable (PortionKey,RN)
 VALUES ('100',1),
        ('0AD',2),
        ('D',3)
SELECT * FROM #finaltable f
SELECT * FROM #portiontable p

SELECT (SELECT ''+ ValuePortionKey
         FROM (
         SELECT f.RN,f.value,P.PortionKey, f.value + P.PortionKey AS ValuePortionKey
FROM #portiontable p 
INNER JOIN #finaltable f ON p.rn = f.rn
         ) ft
FOR XML PATH('')) as PartSignature


DROP TABLE #portiontable
DROP TABLE #finaltable
```

The desired output is 2 rows:

```
PartSignature
KRM__21X0E100C0ADD
KRM__21X0J100K0ADD
```

The actual output is:

```
PartSignature
KRM__21X0E100C0ADDKRM__21X0J100K0ADD
```

Comment: Please do not poste pictures. Try to set up a [mcve].

Comment: I tried, but it showed that I've to get 10 reputations before posting Images not embedding it

Comment: No, it's not a question of *embedding images*... I ask you to type some DDL and INSERT statements to set up a *stand-alone, self-running* example. The minimum was a set of sample input in a copy-paste format.

Comment: @AbdallahAbdulghany **don't post images at all**. Images can't be copied, executed or used to test queries. Post the SQL script needed to create the tables, add the test data and *explain the logic behind the expected result*

Comment: Oh Okay, The Images were for the query result not the code itself.

Comment: BTW SQL Server 2017 and later have `STRING_AGG`, there's no need for XML to perform string aggregation. The XML snippet you used performs an aggregation, just like `SUM()` or `MAX()` do. You need a `GROUP BY` clause if you want to aggregate on a subset of the data

Comment: Is it on purpose that you add the same record to finaltable twice?

Comment: @Tyron78 I think he just wants to show the data's in rows than added strings of data.

Comment: yes, it's a signature.

Comment: @jahirul-islam-monir Yes Exactly

Comment: You have 2 sets of information in the `#finaltable`. You need another column to identify one set from another

Comment: @Squirrel How could I do that ?

Comment: where is this result comes from `KRM__21X0J100K0ADD` ? I don't see it in your sample data

Comment: Identify where one set ends. In the #FinalTable, there are 8 rows, you have to specify where one set ends. If you think, one set consists of 3 rows then fine.

Comment: Your current output merging 6 strings into one, you are wanting to split it into two consisting of 3 strings in one set.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, it seems that you have 2 sets of data in the `#finaltable`. You need another column to identify it as a set. I have added a `ValueSet` in the `#finaltable`.

And, I think your sample data does not correspond to the expected output. I have amended the sample data for `#finaltable`

And finally, using [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to perform the string concatenation, you can then `GROUP BY` the new `ValueSet`

```
CREATE TABLE #portiontable 
(
    PortionKey NVARCHAR(100),
    RN         INT,
)

CREATE TABLE #finaltable 
(
    ValueSet INT,
    Value     NVARCHAR(100),
    RN         INT,
)

 INSERT INTO #portiontable (PortionKey,RN)
 VALUES ('100',1),
        ('0AD',2),
        ('D',3)

 INSERT INTO #finaltable (ValueSet,Value,RN)
 VALUES (1,'KRM__21X0E',1),
        (1,'C',2),
        (1,'',3),
        (1,'',4),
        (2,'KRM__21X0J',1),
        (2,'K',2),
        (2,'',3),
        (2,'',4)


SELECT  f.ValueSet, 
        STRING_AGG (f.Value + p.PortionKey, '') AS ValuePortionKey
FROM    #portiontable p
        INNER JOIN #finaltable f    ON  p.RN    = f.RN
GROUP BY f.ValueSet

DROP TABLE #portiontable
DROP TABLE #finaltable

-- Result
1   KRM__21X0E100C0ADD
2   KRM__21X0J100K0ADD
```

Comment: Okay, I see your point here, but I just gave some sample data to apply the concept, in the real case I have over 10K record like this and the grouping thing should be automated not manually inserted.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by `manually inserted`. My point is, you need another column to identify the `set`

Comment: Okay, I'll Try to find a way how to insert that column

Comment: there should be an existing column in your actual table that you can use to identify the `set`. Be it a column like what I have here or an `ID` column with running number. Else it is a design flaw

Comment: Okay, Thank you :)